# Rails - merge two tables with identical structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, append

In my model I've got two tables with identical structure:

```
League1
id  other_columns  match_starts_at  main_page
----------------------------------------------
1   xxxxxxxxxxxxx  24/06/2018       1
2   xxxxxxxxxxxxx  26/06/2018       1
```

and

```
League2
id  other_columns  match_starts_at  main_page
----------------------------------------------
1   xxxxxxxxxxxxx  23/06/2018       1
2   xxxxxxxxxxxxx  25/06/2018       1
```

My controller does something like this:

```
league1 = League1.where(main_page: 1)
leageu2 = League2.where(main_page : 1)
```

How can I mix (append, unite, or any other english word for that) records from both leagues into one object, so that I can later order it by `match_starts_at`?

Something like this:

```
@leagues = league1 + league2
@leagues.order(match_starts_at: :desc)
```

But it results in error:
`undefined method 'order' for #<Array:0x007f0338c02898>`

And my desired result is this (sorted by match_starts_by):

```
League2
id  other_columns  match_starts_at  main_page
----------------------------------------------
1   xxxxxxxxxxxxx  23/06/2018       1
1   xxxxxxxxxxxxx  24/06/2018       1
2   xxxxxxxxxxxxx  25/06/2018       1
2   xxxxxxxxxxxxx  25/06/2018       1
```

And then I paginate it and send it to my view.

Comment: You can use `sort_by`: https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Yes, but then I can't paginate it because it's an array, not object returned by activerecord

Comment: It throws error `undefined method 'order' for #<Array:0x007f0338c02898` because `order` is a  part of `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods` therefore you can call it only on an `ActiveRecord` instance

Comment: Google or search SO for `UNION` or change your DB structure to have one `leagues` table.

Comment: Anyone eager to show how to do it step by step? I found some solutions but I don't understand them so I don't know how to tailor them for this specific case

Comment: What are you using for pagination @MaciejDobosz?

Comment: `gem 'kaminari'`, and it needs a standard ActiveRecord relation to work with

Comment: It turns out that `kaminari` that I use for pagination also accepts `Array`, I've posted an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

I can now answer my own question.

I didn't manage to merge these two `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects into one, but it turned out that having `Array` on the output was also sufficient here.

What I did:

```
league1 = League1.where(main_page: 1) #ActiveRecord::Relation
leageu2 = League2.where(main_page : 1) #ActiveRecord::Relation

@leagues = league1 + league2 #which returns Array

@league = @league.sort_by { |r| r.match_starts_at }.reverse #sorting a normal array

@league = Kaminari.paginate_array(@league).page(params[:page]).per(10) # it turned out Kaminari can also paginate Array using #paginate_array
```